# What are real numbers in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

What are real numbers in Dafny. Are they represented as IEEE 754-2008 floating point numbers? If not, then what are they? I.e., what is the specification of the real type in Dafny?

Comment: if you find an answer helpful, please upvote it, and accept the one that is best. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dafny's `real` numbers are not floating point numbers.

From a verification perspective, they are the mathematical real numbers, and Dafny reasons about them using Z3's theory of real arithmetic.

From a compilation perspective, Dafny actually compiles them to `BigRational`s, which is made possible by the fact that Dafny doesn't have any builtin operations for creating irrational real numbers.